# Subtitle like text always facing to the camera

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am using the blender cycles render as png or jpg in first step and than I add these images to create a movie. It will help render in parts for me.

I want to add the text in the video that always facing to the camera, like a subtitle.

I tried to add the text and align it to the camera but result is not very good [like this](https://youtu.be/7Gk3S5YsL8I)

Is there a way to add such text? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just add a Text Effect strip in the VSE

Comment: Thank you that will be really helpful, is it possible to adjust the fonts?

Comment: You can use a "copy rotation" constraint on any object, target to the camera

Comment: There is a typo in your video. The color is "grey", not "gray".

Comment: @yann https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey

Comment: Oh, i didn't know that. Well, that's embarassing.

Comment: @BlenderForYou unfortunately as of 2.79 it's not possible to alter the font, only some of its properties.

Comment: @BlenderForYou now it's possible to change the font in the new [2.8 beta](https://www.blendernation.com/2019/01/15/blender-developers-meeting-notes-14-january-2019/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Setup a new **Scene** for text.
2. Select the Camera and change it to **Orthographic**.

   *Properties > Data*(Camera icon) *> Lens > Orthographic*

[image: Options for no perspective and Scale]

3. **Reset** Camera **Location** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) and **Rotation**
   (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).
4. **Move** Camera along *Z-axis* till it is above 0.
5. **Text Object** can be place on the *X-Y plan* as you like.

---

To combine the *animation* and *text*, crate another new **Scene** and import the 2 Scenes into **VSE**.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but another way of achieving can be just making the text a child of the camera, so wherever the camera rotates the text will always face the camera.

Though, a 2nd step would be needed to make the text render on top of all other objects for cases where they come between the camera and the text.